# Why doesn't onanimationend work in my code, but addEventListener("animationend") does?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to remove an element once its fade animation has ended. Adding a listener to the `animationend` event works fine, but assigning the handler to `.onanimationend` doesn't - the function does not fire when the animation ends. Why doesn't the `on-` handler work?

I'm running the code on FF 48, but the problem also occurs on Chrome 71.

```js
const post = document.querySelector('.post');
const hideButton = post.children[0];

// When hide button is clicked, run fade animation.
hideButton.onclick = function() {
  post.style.animationPlayState = "running";
};

// This function runs
post.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  console.log('animationend listener running');
  // this.remove();
});

// This function doesn't run
post.onanimationend = function() {
  console.log('onanimationend handler running');
  // this.remove();
};
```

```css
@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}

.post {
  background-color: #80ff00;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 15px;
  animation-name: hide;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  Post
  <button class="hide">
    Hide
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure. https://jsfiddle.net/fL4xn7w6/10/

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Chrome 71. The element looks to get removed properly on FF 56. Sounds like a browser issue rather than a problem with your code.

Comment: Yeah, in fact it is a browser problem. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser version and compare with
https://caniuse.com/#search=animationend

> Firefox v48.0.0 – Java Broker 36 mins ago

Your browser isn't compatible with `animationend`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I'm not trying to run 2 event handlers in the same time. I just gave an example of one function that works and another function that doesn't. For comparison purpose.

Comment: onanimationend doesn't work in my code. Even if I'm just logging something to the console. But if I use addEventListener instead, it works fine.

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: Firefox v48.0.0

Comment: I can see the property when I inspect DOM properties and there is full support according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onanimationend#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Bro v48 isn't supporting it completely

Comment: But the newest version of Chrome doesn't seem to understand it either. Also, from your caniuse link, FF 5+ *does* support CSS animations. Seems like something deeper is going on.

Comment: Might be something for bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Chrome still doesn't and FF 45 still didn't support [`HTMLElement.onanimationend`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/#event-handlers-on-elements-document-objects-and-window-objects) handler.
I can't tell for Firefox 45 (that you should update btw), but Chrome does support the [GlobalEventHandler's one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onanimationend) (`window`), which explains why handlers attached via `EventTarget.addEventListener` will catch it.

```js
window.onanimationend = e => {
  // stacksnippet's console also has CSS animations...
  if(e.animationName === 'roundify')
  console.log({ // logging the full event will kill the page
    target: e.target,
    type: e.type,
    animationName: e.animationName
  });
}
```

```css
#anim {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  animation: roundify 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes roundify {
  100% { border-radius: 50%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="anim"></div>
```

Now if you really need the HTMLElement and Document handlers, you can very well implement it yourself, but note that it's generally a bad idea to change such DOM prototypes.

```js
// now we only have our Element's event

anim.onanimationend = e => console.log({ // logging the full event will kill the page
    target: e.target,
    type: e.type,
    animationName: e.animationName
  });
```

```css
#anim{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  animation: roundify 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes roundify {
  100% { border-radius: 50%; }
}
```

```html
<script>
// This does modify both HTMLElement and Document protoypes,
// should be placed at top most position in the doc possible
(function(){
  if(
    !("onanimationend" in HTMLElement.prototype) &&
    window.onanimationend !== undefined
  ) {
    // will attach the handler on a the Object's `__animationendhandler` property
    const getsetanimationend =   {
      get: function() {
        return this._animationendhandler || null
      },
      set: function(func) {
        this.removeEventListener('animationend', this._animationendhandler);
        if(typeof func !== 'function') {
          this._animationendhandler = null;
          return;
        }
        this._animationendhandler = func;
        this.addEventListener('animationend', func);
      }
    };

    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onanimationend', getsetanimationend);
    Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, 'onanimationend', getsetanimationend);
  }
})();
</script>
<div id="anim"></div>
```